# Display count in dynamic ranges in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I am creating ranges based on maximum value in table. For example if maximum value in table is 45 then it will create ranges like 0-10 11-20  21-30 31-40 41-50 and then want to show count in that ranges. Below what I try in SQL

```
DECLARE @VariableData TABLE (id INT, [label] NVARCHAR(50), PendingDays INT )

INSERT INTO @VariableData (id, [label], PendingDays) VALUES(1, 'Red', 5)
INSERT INTO @VariableData (id, [label], PendingDays) VALUES(2, 'Green', 7)
INSERT INTO @VariableData (id, [label], PendingDays) VALUES(3, 'Yellow', 25)
INSERT INTO @VariableData (id, [label], PendingDays) VALUES(4, 'Brown', 27)
INSERT INTO @VariableData (id, [label], PendingDays) VALUES(5, 'Black', 45)
INSERT INTO @VariableData (id, [label], PendingDays) VALUES(6, 'Red', 8)
INSERT INTO @VariableData (id, [label], PendingDays) VALUES(7, 'Red', 11)
INSERT INTO @VariableData (id, [label], PendingDays) VALUES(8, 'Green', 22)
INSERT INTO @VariableData (id, [label], PendingDays) VALUES(9, 'Black', 1)

SELECT * 
FROM @VariableData
```

I get this result:

[image]

I want to show result like below

[image]

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is to use CASE with an aggregation.

```
SELECT [label], 
       SUM(CASE WHEN Pending Days BETWEEN 0 AND 10 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [0-10],
       SUM(CASE WHEN Pending Days BETWEEN 11 AND 20 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [11-20]
FROM @VariableData
GROUP BY [label]
```

Comment: cool but ranges are dynamic based on max value of table and also i have to count pending days rows in that range

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate the range and just divide into five groups based on calculations on the range:

```
select vd.*,
       floor((pendingdays - min_pendingdays) * 5.0 / (max_pendingdays - min_pendingdays + 1)) as tile
from (select vd.*,
             min(pendingdays) over () as min_pendingdays,
             max(pendingdays) over () as max_pendingdays
      from VariableData vd
     ) vd;
```

This puts the results in *rows*.  You can the aggregate these into columns:

```
select label,
       sum(case when tile = 0 then 1 end) as tile_1,
       sum(case when tile = 1 then 1 end) as tile_2,
       sum(case when tile = 2 then 1 end) as tile_3,
       sum(case when tile = 3 then 1 end) as tile_4,
       sum(case when tile = 4 then 1 end) as tile_5
from (select vd.*,
             floor((pendingdays - min_pendingdays) * 5.0 / (max_pendingdays - min_pendingdays + 1)) as tile
      from (select vd.*,
                   min(pendingdays) over () as min_pendingdays,
                   max(pendingdays) over () as max_pendingdays
            from VariableData vd
           ) vd
     ) vd
group by label;
```

The only caveat is that you cannot name the columns based on values in the data.  That requires dynamic SQL.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=ddd1770270bfee376776040c2eb977aa) is a db<>fiddle.